# How to convert a list of numbers to decimal format?

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, string.format

`mask = [11111111, 11111111, 11111111, 00000000]` -> 255.255.255.0

The bottom line is that it's a *list*. I don't know if it's possible to write something like 'dec' in brackets and apply the *.format*. It is also problematic to convert a list of elements into a string and apply *int* to binary code for each element.

`print('{0:dec}.{1:dec}.{2:dec}.{3:dec}'.format(*mask))` - this of course can't work, just to understand what I'm trying to do.

If possible, I'd like to avoid iterating over the list(*if in*).

Comment: Applying a function to all elements of a list is covered extensively in documentation, tutorials, and other questions here. Please note that asking on Stack Overflow isn't a [substitute for doing your own research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Your list contains integers that happen to look like binary numbers. Therefore:

```
mask = [11111111, 11111111, 11111111, 00000000]

print('.'.join(str(int(str(e), 2)) for e in mask))
```

**Output:**

```
255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to apply a map() function.

```
mask = [11111111, 11111111, 11111111, 00000000] #-> 255.255.255.0
mapped = list(map(lambda x: int(str(x),2), mask))
print(mapped)
```

outputs:

```
[255, 255, 255, 0]
```

then you can format string:

```
print('.'.join(str(e) for e in mapped))
```

outputs:

```
255.255.255.0
```

Comment: **Thanks**

    `str_bin_mask = '11111111111111111111111100000000'
    mask_temp = '{0:08b} {1:08b} {2:08b} {3:08b}'
    
    lst_dec_mask = [int(str_bin_mask[:8], 2)]
    lst_dec_mask.append(int(str_bin_mask[8:16], 2))
    lst_dec_mask.append(int(str_bin_mask[16:24], 2))
    lst_dec_mask.append(int(str_bin_mask[24:32], 2))
    
    print(mask_temp.format(*lst_dec_mask))`

It turned out to be easier to take a step back and get a list of _decimal_ values, and only then apply the _.format_. It still looks massive though...